# Cannot Instantiate an Instance of an Added Form

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, c#-4.0

I've been working on a C#/Winforms project for a few days now in Visual Studio 2008 and I decided to add a new form. so, I right click on my Project's name and chose "Add" then "Windows Form".

I gave it a useful name - something like "TestToolForm.cs" - then checked that it was using the same namespace as the rest of the project. I hit "save", then "Build". Everything's going ok.

I then tried to create an instance of it in (form) button click event and get the following error message:

```
The type or namespace name 'TestToolForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The error is being thrown on the following code block - on both instances of the word "TestToolForm":

```
private void btnTestTool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TestToolForm testForm = new TestToolForm();
}
```

My TestToolForm.cs contains exactly the following, as I was going to add the internal logic afterwards:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myNameSpace
{
    public partial class TestToolForm : Form
    {
        public TestToolForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The funny thing is, I've added all of my other forms this way, and none of them has caused this error before.

I've looked around a little on here, Google, DaniWeb and other places.

- I've checked that I have matching parentheses and curly braces (it wouldn't have compiled before, otherwise).
- I've closed down Visual Studio, restarted my machine and started VS back up.
- I've checked that I'm compiling against the client version of .NET 4
- I've made sure that both the .NET framework and Visual Studio I have installed are up to date.
- I've done a clean solution and rebuild.

Is there something obvious that I might have missed?

Comment: `then checked that it was using the same namespace`.  That's a curious thing to do.  Did you change the namespace name?  Does the Default namespace setting in Project + Properties, Application tab match?  Easy explanation for the error.

Comment: @HansPassant I checked that on the off chance that I had changed the namespace (either for this form or the rest of the project) somehow. It was just one of the things that I thought I should check, on the off chance that something had corrupted or changed it. Turns out that the namespace is correct anyway

Comment: Do you really need the 'partial' definition? What happens if you remove it? Is the call to instantiate - within the same assembly, or do you need to reference the assembly where the TestToolForm resides?

Comment: The only error i can think of is having a different namespace. Are you sure it's exactly (MyNameSpace != myNameSpace) the same in both .cs files?

Answer (score 3):

i also had the exact same problem, as described in this post. I was also thinking that i have given the same namespace, but when i closely checked my namespace, i found that there was a difference of 1 character. Glad i found this question on SO that made me look over the namespace again.

So please double check your namespace, try copy and pasting the name namespace on the new Form from your old file. Hope it helps.